# How to combine multiple subscription

Tags: angularjs

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.getSubordinatesByAppUserId(this.appUserId);
        this.getHistoricalRecordsByUserId(this.appUserId);
}


getSubordinatesByAppUserId(id) {
       this.appUserService.findByReportTo(id)
            .subscribe((appUserResponse: HttpResponse<AppUser[]>) => {
                this.subordinates = appUserResponse.body;
            });
    }



getHistoricalRecordsByUserId(id){
    this.jobPostingService.findHistoricalRecById(id)
        .subscribe((jobPostingResponse: HttpResponse<JobPosting[]>) => {
            this.historyRec = jobPostingResponse.body;
            console.log("test >>"+this.historyRec.length);
            // console.log("test >>"+JSON.stringify(this.client));
        });
}
```

i got problem when run this code because .subscribe cannot get 2 data immediately. is there any simple way to overcome this problem?

Comment: What is Error Coming on ruuning the code , please give sample output so that users can help easily –

Comment: What is the goal? Why do you want 2 sets of data "immediately"?